# Cookies not saving in chrome

Tags: jquery, cookies

What wrong me? I get is only firefox browser by this way.I not get it chrome,safari and opera.
**html**

```
<a href="javascript:" class="red-btn">red</a>
<a href="javascript:" class="green-btn">green</a>

<!-- Result -->
<div class="red" >Testing Text1</div>
<div class="red" >Testing Text2</div>
```

**css**

```
.red {
            color: red;

}
.green {
            color: green;

}
```

**Jquery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //check if cookie has been set
    var cookieColor = $.cookie("selected_class");
    if (cookieColor) {
          //remove default "red" class and add cookie class
          $(".red").removeClass("red").addClass(cookieColor);
    }

    jQuery(document).on('click',".red-btn",function (){
        alert("red color");
         //store the value
         $.cookie("selected_class", "red");

        jQuery(".green").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
    });
    jQuery(document).on('click',".green-btn",function (){
        alert("green color");

         //store the value
         $.cookie("selected_class", "green");
        jQuery(".red").removeClass("red").addClass("green");
    });
});
```

**[My working demo is http://jsfiddle.net/h5mk2dsb/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/h5mk2dsb/3/)**

Comment: Well... it works in my Chorme...

Comment: Yup, and also Firefox. IE11 shows an Access Denied error when trying to set the color, though, could be a clue.

Comment: @Naykyi what version of jQuery are you using? 1.9.1?

Comment: I using 1.8.3 jquery version.